# Fragment inherit from another one with atribute initialization

Tags: android

```
public class CartMain extends BasicFragment implements EditMenuInterface {...}

public abstract class BasicFragment extends Fragment  {
    protected ArrayList<Integer> selectedElements = new ArrayList<>();
    protected RecyclerView listView;
    protected ObservableArrayList<?> list;
    protected boolean editMode = false;;
    protected View managementMenu

             ... methods...
}
```

I would like to initialize the parameters in BasicFragments in the CartMain class, but since i cant use constructrs i dont know how is the right way to do it.

I'm doing like this:

```
CartMain Class
 @Override
public View onCreateView...{
mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cart_main, container, false);
listView = view.findById...
list = cartDAO.getAll();
listView = mainView.findViewById(R.id.cart_list_itemCarts);
```

`}`

But i dont know if its correct, because when we use constructors its obrigatory initializate the super class atributes, but using onCreateView its not obrigatory.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few points about your fragment:

1. be sure to declare an empty public constructor with no arguments:

`public CartMain(){}`

without that *public* empty constructor, Android will crash if you put your calling activity onPause and if it gets garbag-collected after some time.

Android will look for this empty public constructor to reinstantiate your fragment in onResume from the main thread.

2. The variables values initialized in the `onCreateView` will be used as default values after onStart, onPause etc. if the app return back to work after being stopped and garbage collected. Not variables, in the class constructor.

Therefore, do all your default initialization in the onCreateView.

You can do it in the super class's onCreateView.

If some initialization is done in the superclass, then in the subclass add the super method right at the start on your onCreateView.

```
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflator li...{
      super(li... // This will call onCeateView in your super class
      ... // where you can initialize 'common-for-all' values, setup listeners
      ... 
      // do everything else

      return mainView;
 }
```

3. And the end of your onCreateView place `return mainView;` that you have inflated. The view that you return is the view that will appear on the screen.

---

Don't use initialization through the constructor outside onCreateView, because if, due to the app going to pause it gets garbage collected, it won't be able to re-initialize.

To verify that your fragment works correctly, use Developer mode (with the settings: Restriction - No background processes, Do not keep activities in memory - or similar settings).